# How to apply debouncetime() to http service - angular 4+

Tags: angular

I have a search box and I want send a request to the server after the user ends to type a word past a few seconds. How could I apply debouncetime() to my service?

Here is my code:

**myComponent.html**

```
<input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Search">
```

**myComponent.ts**

```
  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
      filterValue = filterValue.trim();
      filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase();
      this.scanService.getFilteringScans(filterValue).subscribe(response => {
        this.scans = response.results;
        this.next = response.next;
        this.previous = response.previous;
        this.scans_length = response.count;
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.scans.map(function(obj){return new ScanDetails(obj)}));
      });
      this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
  }
```

**myService.ts**

```
 getFilteringScans(param): Observable<ScanList> {
    return this.http.get<ScanList>(this.scansUrl + '?search=' + param).pipe(
      map(response => response),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }
```

Could anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working with Angular, you can actually make use of RxJS's [debounceTime](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/debouncetime.html) operator.

```
import { debounceTime, map, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

.
.
onChange = new Subject<string>();

ngOnInit() {
  this.subscription = this.onChange
    .pipe( 
      debounceTime(1000),
      switchMap(search => this.applyFilter(search)),
    ).subscribe();
}

applyFilter(value) {
  this.onChange.next(value);
}
```

Comment: That's good, but it is better to move the Service call to the `subscribe` `next` handler.
Or even better, create a new `Observable` which will be used to display results.

Comment: You are right. Something like `.debounceTime(1000)).subscribe(search => this.applyfilter());` instead?

Comment: Almost, it should be a call to `getFilteringScans(searchValue)` instead of `applySearch()`.
I would just `switchMap` to produce a new Observable, and let `async` subscribe in the template.

Comment: @LppEdd Good point!! But I was thinking that the OP wanted to use `.trim()` and `.toLowerCase()`, that is why I decide to call the entire method instead..

Comment: Just add a `map` step for that.

Comment: Thank you for your code @wentjun but the code doesn't work. I've tried it in my code and some errors appears.

Comment: @wentjun the first error comes from "this.subscription" that I presume is a variable that I must declare and the second error comes from "switchMap(search => this.applyFilter())" which error says "Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.".

Comment: @BeatrizIC yes, my bad. It should be `switchMap(search => this.applyFilter(search))`. And yes, you need to define the property in your class called `subscription`